# How to delete a H2 database file programmatically?

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I'm developing an application using JDBC and an H2 database, and occasionally there is a need to delete the database file. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Tutorial: [Deleting a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html)

Comment: By the way, if you need a temporary database without persistence, H2 supports “in-memory” mode where the database lives only in memory, never gets written to storage, and disappears when your app exits.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can!

Refer to this answer to locate the folder where H2 stores the database (usually user's home directory):
 [Where does H2's Embedded Databases Store the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461770/where-does-h2s-embedded-databases-store-the-data)

To delete it, you can use the org.h2.tools.DeleteDbFiles class as follows:

```
DeleteDbFiles.execute(dbDir, dbName, true);
```

More info about DeleteDbFiles class: http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/DeleteDbFiles.html

Comment: this does not work, try creating table then call this method and again try to create the table with the same name, it will still throw an error as the table is already exists

Answer (score 2):

```
Statement s = connection.createStatement();
s.execute("drop all objects delete files");
```